# Send variable value to other local page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to make a scoreboard for my darts scoring program, which I programmed in HTML. Basically, it is a program to keep the players' scores while playing darts. I have it all in one document right now, but I would like to have one page open to enter the scoring, for example on a tablet to punch in the scores, and another page open on another device, like a computer, which would be connected to the same network as the tablet used to punch in the data.

Here is the dart scoring program I already made: https://chrisle5512.github.io/dartscore/

So basically, I would like to make a separate page to display the scores only, instead of having them on the same display as the scoring tablet, so that we can see it bigger than on part of a tablet screen. I would go to the URL on my PS4 to show the score on my TV. I just don't know how to send the inputted data from the scoring page (tablet) to another local page (PS4).

If anyone could tell me how to share variable values inputted from one HTML page, to another HTML page on the same local network in real time, preferably using Javascript and avoiding jQuery, I would really appreciate it! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sounds like you need to upload to a database of some kind, JavaScript probably isn't your best option here.

Comment: You will either need some kind of server backend or set up something using WebRTC. However, this question is too broad to be adequately answered here.

Answer (score 0):

You solution require a backend to work on. You are essentially talking about 3 interfaces, one interface to input the data, one interface to show the data, and one interface (which you are missing with) is the backend which will coordinate the data between the first two interfaces.

The backend cannot be built with HTML, you will need some sort of scripting language for that, like PHP or others. Once that build, you can synchronize the other two interfaces using javascript (without jquery) with the backend and that will give you the desired functionality.